# How to validate auto complete component inside angular stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

```html
<form [formGroup]="assetformGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit('update')" #formone="ngForm">
    <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" [linear]="true" #stepper formArrayName="formArray">
        <mat-step formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray.get([0])">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Asset</ng-template>
            <mat-card class="card-min-height">
                <div class="mat-custom-container">

                    <table cellspacing="0" class="full-width padding-right">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="assetName" matInput formControlName="name" autocomplete="off"
                                           placeholder=" Asset Name" maxlength="255" required>
                                    <mat-error>Asset Name is required</mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width under-line">
                                    <mat-chip-list #alterNativeNameList>
                                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let term of alterNativeName" [selectable]="selectable"
                                                  [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(term, alterNativeName)">
                                            {{term}}
                                            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                                        </mat-chip>
                                        <input name="alterNativeName" placeholder="Alternative Names"
                                               [matChipInputFor]="alterNativeNameList"
                                               [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                                               [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                                               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                                    </mat-chip-list>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <mat-chip-list #searchTermChipList>
                                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let term of searchTerm" [selectable]="selectable"
                                                  [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(term, searchTerm)">
                                            {{term}}
                                            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                                        </mat-chip>
                                        <input name="searchTerm"
                                               [matChipInputFor]="searchTermChipList"
                                               [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                                               [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                                               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
                                               placeholder="Search Terms (Enter keywords associated with asset)">
                                    </mat-chip-list>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="cecoLength" matInput formControlName="cecoLength" type="number"
                                           autocomplete="off" maxlength="11" placeholder="Ceco Length (Time in sec)" value="15">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="metaDataKey" matInput formControlName="metaDataKey"
                                           autocomplete="off"
                                           placeholder="Meta Data Key">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <mat-chip-list #metaDataChipList>
                                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let term of metaData" [selectable]="selectable"
                                                  [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(term, metaData)">
                                            {{term}}
                                            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                                        </mat-chip>
                                        <input name="metaData" placeholder="Meta Data"
                                               [matChipInputFor]="metaDataChipList"
                                               [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                                               [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                                               (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                                    </mat-chip-list>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="bucketURL" placeholder="Bucket URL"
                                           maxlength="1000" matInput formControlName="bucketURL"
                                    value="s3://armada-data-eu-west-2/prod">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="language" placeholder="Language"
                                           maxlength="2" matInput formControlName="language">
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div>
                        <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step formGroupName="1" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([1])">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Collection</ng-template>
            <mat-card class="card-min-height">
                <div class="mat-custom-container">
                    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="4:1" rowHeight="100px">
                        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1"
                                       [rowspan]="1">
                            <div class="select-full-width">
                                <app-dynamic-select table_name="collectionGroup"
                                                    placeholder="Select Collection Group *"
                                                    [selectedValue]="collectionGroupValue"
                                                    (messageEvent)="receiveMessageFromColGrp($event)"
                                                    (collectionGroupValueEvent)="collectionGroupValueEventFun($event)"
                                >
                                </app-dynamic-select>
                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>

                        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1"
                                       [rowspan]="1">
                            <div class="select-full-width">
                                <app-dynamic-select table_name="collections"
                                                    placeholder="Select Collection *" [selectedValue]="collectionValue"
                                                    (messageEvent)="receiveMessageFromCollection($event)">
                                </app-dynamic-select>
                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>

                        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1"
                                       [rowspan]="1">
                            <div class="pull-left select-full-width">
                                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
                                <button type="button" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>
                    </mat-grid-list>
                </div>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step formGroupName="2" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([2])">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Rights holder</ng-template>
            <mat-card class="card-min-height">
                <div class="mat-custom-container">
                    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="4:1" rowHeight="100px">
                        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1"
                                       [rowspan]="1">
                            <div class="select-full-width">
                                <app-dynamic-select table_name="rightsholderGroup"
                                                    placeholder="Select Rightsholder Group *"
                                                    [selectedValue]="rightsholderGroupValue"
                                                    (messageEvent)="openPopupRightsholderGroup($event)">
                                </app-dynamic-select>
                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>


                        <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="1"
                                       [rowspan]="1">
                            <div class="select-full-width">
                                <app-dynamic-multi-select table_name="rightsholders"
                                                          placeholder="Select Rightsholder *"
                                                          [selectedItem]="rightsholderValue"
                                                          (popupEventRightsholderGroup)="openPopupRightsholderGroup($event)"
                                                          (messageEvent)="openPopupRightsholder($event)"
                                                          (rightsholderGroupValueEvent)="rightsholderGroupValueEventFun($event)"
                                >
                                </app-dynamic-multi-select>

                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>



                        <mat-grid-tile>
                            <div class="pull-left select-full-width">
                                <div>
                                    <button mat-button matStepperPrevious type="button">Back</button>
                                    <button mat-button matStepperNext type="button">Next</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </mat-grid-tile>
                    </mat-grid-list>
                </div>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
            <mat-card class="card-min-height">
                <div class="mat-custom-container">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            {{"Please review and submit."}}
                        </div>


                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Asset Name :-</b> {{assetName}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Alternative Names :-</b>
                                <mat-chip-list *ngFor="let item of alterNativeName ; let i=index">
                                    <mat-chip>{{item }}</mat-chip>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-grid-tile>

                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Search Terms :-</b>
                                <mat-chip-list *ngFor="let item of searchTerm ; let i=index">
                                    <mat-chip>{{item }}</mat-chip>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Ceco Length :-</b> {{" "+cecoLength}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Search Terms will be store in database like :-</b>
                                <pre>{{searchTerm | json}}</pre>
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile></mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Meta Data Key:-</b>{{" "+metaDataKey}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>

                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Meta Data Values:-</b>
                                <mat-chip-list *ngFor="let item of metaData ; let i=index">
                                    <mat-chip>{{item }}</mat-chip>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-grid-tile>

                            <!--<mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Media Info :-</b>
                                <mat-chip-list *ngFor="let item of mediaInfo ; let i=index">
                                    <mat-chip>{{item }}</mat-chip>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-grid-tile>-->
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Bucket URL :-</b> {{bucketURL}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Language :-</b>  {{language}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Collection Group :-</b> {{collectionGroupValue && collectionGroupValue.Name}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Collection :-</b> {{collectionValue && collectionValue.Name}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Rightsholder Group :-</b> {{rightsholderGroupValue && rightsholderGroupValue.Name}}
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                            <mat-grid-tile>
                                <b>Rightsholder :-</b>
                                <mat-chip-list *ngFor="let item of rightsholderValue ; let i=index">
                                    <mat-chip>{{item.Name }}</mat-chip>
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-grid-tile>
                        </mat-grid-list>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                       <!-- <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>-->
                        <button type="submit" mat-button>submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card>
        </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</form>
```

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Access form in .ts file and do like I did in the following example.

```
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  // creates the internal firstName FormControl
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  // creates the internal lastName FormControl
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: Your right for below code.  <td>
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                    <input [(ngModel)]="assetName" matInput formControlName="name" autocomplete="off"
                                           placeholder=" Asset Name" maxlength="255" required>
                                    <mat-error>Asset Name is required</mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </td>

Comment: <app-dynamic-select >
                                </app-dynamic-select>
                            But how can i validate this component inside stepeer?